# Magento 2.3 sortOrders not working in search rest API

Tags: magento2.3, sorting

I tried to pass sort order in V1/search API as below but the sorting is not working in the result.

```
searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=price
searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC
```

Anyone has idea for the same?